# PowerShell: Unique Array of Objects

Tags: powershell

I've got an array of objects for team names and emails as well as the tickets associated to that team in a seperate array however its not working quite as expected and I've been stumped on this one for sometime...

code:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName='Team1';
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

$collectionWithItems = @()
$array = @()

foreach ($i in $results) {
    foreach ($x in $teamConfig) {
        if ($i.TeamName -eq $x.TeamName) {
            $array += $i.TicketID

            $temp = New-Object System.Object
            $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TeamName" -Value $i.TeamName
            $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TeamEmail" -Value $i.TeamEmail
            $temp | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "TicketID" -Value $array
            $collectionWithItems += $temp
        }
    }
}

$collectionWithItems = $collectionWithItems | select 'TeamName', 'TeamEmail', 'TicketID' -Unique

$collectionWithItems
```

Output:

```
TeamName TeamEmail      TicketID
-------- ---------      --------
Team1    Team1@test.com {INC0001}
Team1    Team1@test.com {INC0001, INC0002}
Team1    Team1@test.com {INC0001, INC0002, INC0003}
Team1    Team1@test.com {INC0001, INC0002, INC0003, INC0004}
```

Desired output:

```
TeamName TeamEmail      TicketID
-------- ---------      --------
Team1    Team1@test.com {INC0001, INC0002, INC0003, INC0004}
```

The other thing I am confused about as well is that this will need to work with multiple teams for example:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName='Team1';
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName='Team2';
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName='Team3';
    }
)
```

and as a result, the desired output should be:

```
TeamName TeamEmail      TicketID
-------- ---------      --------
Team1    Team1@test.com {INC0001, INC0002, INC0003, INC0004}
Team2    Team2@test.com {INC0005, INC0006, INC0007, INC0008}
Team3    Team3@test.com {INC0009, INC0010, INC0011, INC0012}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer loop should iterate over `$teamConfig` so that you only go through each team *once*.

To get the tickets associated with the current team name, you can use `Where-Object`, like so:

```
$ticketIds = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select -ExpandProperty TicketID
```

Allowing you to simplify your code greatly:

```
$teamConfig = @(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team1'
        TeamEmail = 'team1@domain.tld'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team2'
        TeamEmail = 'team2@domain.tld'
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TeamName  = 'Team3'
        TeamEmail = 'team3@domain.tld'
    }
)

$query = "select * from INCAutomation"

$results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $query -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'AyushTest'

$teamTickets = foreach($team in $teamConfig){
  # Filter tickets based on team name
  $ticketIds = $results |Where-Object TeamName -eq $team.TeamName |Select -ExpandProperty TicketID

  # Output a single object per team, with all ticket IDs attached
  $team |Select TeamName,TeamEmail,@{Name='TicketID';Expression={ $ticketIds }}
}
```

`$teamTickets` now contains exactly one object per team in `$teamConfig`.